# Nodes not deactivated when process is ended

Tags: ros, rospy, nodes, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

***What I am doing***
I am running the ROS Tutorial [Writing a Publisher (python)](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29).

***What I am using***
Ubuntu 16.04
ROS kinetic
Python 2.7

***What I want to know***
I built the code using `catkin_make`. When running the simple publisher ("talker") provided in the tutorial (see code down below) and check for running nodes I get

```
$ rosnode list
/rosout
/talker_9026_1529404131936  # since I set anonymous=True
The talker works fine, the listener gets the data as expected. But when stopping the talker (e.g. press **ctr + c** or closing the terminal-window) the talker-node does not deactivate and is still visible in `rosnode list`. When restarting the node it starts a new node "/talker" with some other number (since anonymous is set True). Setting `anonymous=False` does not change this behaviour.   
How can I properly end my node when stopping the process? I can end it manually using `$ roskill rosmaster`, but that's not what I want.
```

Talker-code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# license removed for brevity
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String

def talker():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('chatter', String, queue_size=10)
    rospy.init_node('talker', anonymous=True)
    rate = rospy.Rate(10) # 10hz
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        hello_str = "hello world %s" % rospy.get_time()
        rospy.loginfo(hello_str)
        pub.publish(hello_str)
        rate.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        talker()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294486/nodes-not-deactivated-when-process-is-ended/) by [benjamin](https://answers.ros.org/users/35921/benjamin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2018-06-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-19**:
just making sure: what is the output of `/usr/bin/env python`?

**Comment by [benjamin](https://answers.ros.org/users/35921/benjamin/) on 2018-06-19**:
I'm using Python 2.7.12:

```
benjamin@ubuntu:~$ /usr/bin/env python

Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Due to my specific terminal-settings pressing **ctr + c** did not  exit the process entirely, but only stopped it (as **ctr + z** in default does). Therefore my node was not ended from being active. Having stopped the process (**ctr + z** in default) even closing the terminal does not end the process.

Still my question is how can I end one node entirely if I only stopped it in the first place?

---

Originally posted by [benjamin](https://answers.ros.org/users/35921/benjamin/) with karma: 26 on 2018-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-22**:
For completeness, see [What is the difference between Ctrl-z and Ctrl-c in the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510811) for some background on `ctrl+z`.

If you suspend all your processes by default, you could kill them with `kill %1` fi. But see the Ask Ubuntu post.